# How do I add an object to my arraylist from data read from a file?

Tags: java, file, parsing, object, arraylist

I know that the data read from my file is parsed and read in correctly but when I try and add it to my `arraylist` of `CTARoute` objects i get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for trying to call a get method from an index that apparently doesn't exist.

Also, there seems to be an issue with the line `reader = new ReadFile();` in `CTARoute`.

**CTARoute class:**

```
public class CTARoute{

        static ReadFile reader;

        private String StationName;
        private double Latitude;
        private double Longitude;
        private String Location;
        private boolean WheelChair;
        private int GreenLine;
        private int RedLine;

        public CTARoute(){

            StationName = "";
            Latitude = 0;
            Longitude = 0;
            Location = "elevated";
            WheelChair = true;
            GreenLine = 0;
            RedLine = 0;

        }

        public CTARoute(String StationName, double Latitude, double Longitude, String Location, boolean wheelChair, int GreenLine,int RedLine){


            this.StationName = StationName;
            this.Latitude = Latitude;
            this.Longitude = Longitude;
            this.Location = Location;
            this.WheelChair = WheelChair;
            this.GreenLine = GreenLine;
            this.RedLine = RedLine;
        }
        public String getStationName(){
            return StationName;
        }
        public Double getLatitude(){
            return Latitude;
        }
        public Double getLongitude(){
            return Longitude;
        }
        public String getLocation(){
            return Location;
        }
        public Boolean getWheelChair(){
            return WheelChair;
        }
        public int getGreenLine(){
            return GreenLine;
        }
        public int getRedLine(){
            return RedLine;
        }

        public void setStationName(String station){
            StationName = station;
        }
        public void setLatitude(double lat){
            Latitude = lat;
        }
        public void setLongitude(double lon){
            Longitude = lon;
        }
        public void setLocation(String loc){
            Location = loc;
        }
        public void setWheelChair(Boolean whe){
            WheelChair = whe;
        }

    public static void main(String args[]){ 

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

         reader = new ReadFile();
}
```

**ReadFile class:**

```
public class ReadFile {

    ArrayList<CTARoute> route;


    public ReadFile(){


     String csvFile = "CTAStops(1).csv";
     File file = new File(csvFile);

     try{

         Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
         inputStream.nextLine();

         while(inputStream.hasNextLine()){

             route = new ArrayList<CTARoute>();

             String data = inputStream.nextLine();
             String var[] = data.split(",");


            route.add(new CTARoute(var[0],Double.parseDouble(var[1]),Double.parseDouble(var[2]),var[3],Boolean.parseBoolean(var[4]),Integer.parseInt(var[5]),Integer.parseInt(var[6])));


         }

         inputStream.close();

     System.out.println(route.get(2).getStationName()); //testing to see if CTARoute objects are actually added to route.....

     }catch (FileNotFoundException e){

         e.printStackTrace();
     }  

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the below code which causes the   `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when a line in your `CTAStops(1).csv` file DOES NOT contain 7 elements with the delimiter ,

```
 route.add(new CTARoute(var[0],Double.parseDouble(var[1]),Double.parseDouble(var[2]),var[3],Boolean.parseBoolean(var[4]),Integer.parseInt(var[5]),Integer.parseInt(var[6])));
```

Also, NOTE that Constructors SHOULD only be used for initializing instance variables of the class (look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctor.html)) and it is NOT best practice to write the complex logic inside constructors (like how you did in your `ReadFile()` which is wrong).
Your code is really hard to read and maintain.